# Javascript's "unescape" in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, validation, url, hyperlink

I have a Google Chrome extension for my image host and it send an URL to my website. That URL gets *encoded* via Javascript's `escape` method.

An URL encoded by `escape` looks like this:

```
http%253A//4.bp.blogspot.com/-xa4Krfq2V6g/UF2K5XYv3kI/AAAAAAAAAJg/8wrqZQP9ru8/s1600/LuffyTimeSkip.png
```

I need to get the URL back to normal via PHP somehow, so I can check it against `filter_var($the_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` and it obviously fails if the URL is like above.

This is how the Javascript looks like:

```
function upload(img) {
    var baseurl="http://imgit.org/remote?sent-urls=1&remote-urls=" + escape(img.srcUrl);
    uploadImage(baseurl);
}
function uploadImage(imgurl) {
        chrome.tabs.create({
        url: imgurl,
        selected: true
    });
}

var title = "Upload this image to IMGit";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts": ['image'], "onclick": upload});
```

And this is what I do in PHP:

```
if (!filter_var($file, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) || !filter_var(urldecode($file), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{
    throw_error('The entered URLs do not have a valid URL format.', 'index.php#remote'); break;
}
```

Frankly, `urldecode()` doesn't do the job for me. And as you can notice, I am receiving the URL via `$_GET`.

What would be the best way to handle this situation?

**Actual question:** How do I *unescape* the escaped URL in PHP? Is there a better way to handle this problem?

Comment: What's `$the_url`? Anything that comes from `$_GET` is decoded automatically.

Comment: Could you post what the url looks like after `urldecode` has run it? Also you may want to look into `encodeUri` as an alternative to `escape`. This [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) may be of some help. Be advised that depending on the receiving server, it may not be able to properly decode the way escape encodes upper ASCII or non-ASCII characters.

Comment: In your `upload` function, if you `alert(img.srcUrl)`, do you get an already encoded url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `escape`:

```
function upload(img) {
    var baseurl="http://imgit.org/remote?sent-urls=1&remote-urls=" + encodeURIComponent(img.srcUrl);
    uploadImage(baseurl);
}
```

Then, you can use `urldecode` inside PHP to get the result you want.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) for an explanation of `escape` vs. `encodeURI` vs. `encodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 2):

**For send in Javascript:**

```
var baseurl="http://imgit.org/remote?sent-urls=1&remote-urls=" + encodeURIComponent(img.srcUrl);
```

**In PHP code**

```
$url = urldecode($_GET["my_url"])
```