# skipping special character when passing through get request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the js\jquery function which is requesting

```
function AssignWork(){
    var projectId = $jq(".dmProjName").val(),
        empId = $jq(".nameEmp").val(),
        assignWork = $jq(".workDescription").val(),
        workDate = $jq(".workDate").val();
    var go_path = "Employee_Switch_Person.php?action=assignWork&vars=4&var1="+empId+"&var2="+projectId+"&var3="+assignWork+"&var4="+workDate;
    $jq.get(go_path,{},function(data){
        if(data ==1){
            alert("Successfully Assigned!");
            showAssignWork(0);
        }
    });
}
```

this is php

```
function assignWork($empId,$projectId,$assignWork,$workDate){
    //echo $workDate;
    global $con;
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
    //echo "date format".date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    //echo $empId.",".$projectId.",".$assignWork.",".$workDate;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tblempassignwork` (`EmpId`, `AssignWork`, `AssignById`, `ProjectId`, `WorkDate`, `AssignDateTime`)
          VALUES($empId,'".$assignWork."',".$_COOKIE["userID"].",".$projectId.",'".$workDate."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $result;
}
```

problem is that

```
 assignWork = $jq(".workDescription").val()
```

can contain a string with double quote, single quote, hash or any special character. if i use single quote or hash then it is showing

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your **MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's and makes some examples',3,77,'2015-05-08','2015-05-08 09:51:17')' at line 2**

cause i have type single quote in string. so how can i skip special character when passing through get request.

Answer (score 0):

In the jQuery, you can replace all the non-alphanumeric characters with `-`

```
assignWork=assignWork.trim().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, '-');
```

Or you can replace it with whitespace or what ever suites your program the best :)

Comment: what will i do when i retrieve this data again

Comment: You can have a backup variable say `var assignWork_original=assignWork`
And then you can do the above trimming

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude special characters

solution is already in stackoverflow
[javascript regexp remove all special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/javascript-regexp-remove-all-special-characters)

```
var outString = sourceString.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
```

Comment: what will i do when i retrieve this data again

Comment: once you replace the character of any string its hard to retrieve again.
you have to store that value in somewhere. If you want value for temporary then store in session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
assignWork = $jq(".workDescription").val(),
```

To this:

```
assignWork = escape($jq(".workDescription").val()),
```

IMHO isn't safe to store te unscaped string in your database, and when you read it back in javascript, you cand just "unescape" it.

[JavaScript unescape() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp)

otherwise, if you want to, just decode it in the PHP using:

```
$assignWork = urldecode($assignWork);
```

[Javascript's “unescape” in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364496/javascripts-unescape-in-php)

Comment: i use escap but problem still persist when i use single quote in WorkDescription string